# Filling the diagonals of square matrices inside a 3D ndarray with values given by a 2D ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 3D ndarray `z` with shape `(k,n,n)`, is it possbile without using iteration to fill the diagonals of the k nxn matrices with values given by a 2D ndarray `v` with shape `(k,n)`?

For example, the result of the operation should be the same as looping over k matrices:

```
z = np.zeros((3,10,10))
v = np.arange(30).reshape((3,10))

for i in range(len(z)): 
    np.fill_diagonal(z[i], v[i])
```

Is there an way to do this without repeatedly calling `np.fill_diagonal` inside a loop? If possible, I would prefer a solution that can be applied to arrays of higher dimensions as well, where `z.shape == (a,b,c,...,k,n,n)` and `v.shape = (a,b,c,...,k,n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's for generic n-dim arrays -

```
diag_view = np.einsum('...ii->...i',z)
diag_view[:] = v
```

Another with reshaping -

```
n = v.shape[-1] 
z.reshape(-1,n**2)[:,::n+1] = v.reshape(-1,n)
# or z.reshape(z.shape[:-2]+(-1,))[...,::n+1] = v
```

Another with `masking` -

```
m = np.eye(n, dtype=bool) # n = v.shape[-1] from earlier
z[...,m] = v
```

**Initializing output `z`**

If we need to initialize the output array `z` and one that will cover for generic n-dim cases, it would be :

```
z = np.zeros(v.shape + (v.shape[-1],), dtype=v.dtype)
```

Then, we proceed with the earlier listed approaches.