# Create identity matrices with arbitrary shape with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, identity

Is there a faster / inbuilt way to generate identity matrices with arbitrary shape in the first dimensions and an identity in the last `m` dimensions?

```
import numpy as np

base_shape = (10, 11, 12)
n_dim = 4

# m = 2
frames2d = np.zeros(base_shape + (n_dim, n_dim))
for i in range(n_dim):
    frames2d[..., i, i] = 1

# m = 3
frames3d = np.zeros(base_shape + (n_dim, n_dim, n_dim))
for i in range(n_dim):
    frames3d[..., i, i, i] = 1
```

Comment: Does np has np.eye?

Comment: yes `numpy` has `eye` but  it is only possible to create `2D` identity matrices

Comment: `frames2d[:] = np.eye(n_dim)` should work (by broadcasting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach #1

We can leverage [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for a diagonal view inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58357200/) and hence assign `1s` there for our desired output. So, for say the `m=3` case, after initializing with zeros, we can simply do -

```
diag_view = np.einsum('...iii->...i',frames3d)
diag_view[:] = 1
```

Generalizing to include those input params, it would be -

```
def ndeye_einsum(base_shape, n_dim, m):
    out = np.zeros(list(base_shape) +  [n_dim]*m)
    diag_view = np.einsum('...'+'i'*m+'->...i',out)
    diag_view[:] = 1
    return out
```

So, to reproduce those same arrays, it would be -

```
frames2d = ndeye_einsum(base_shape, n_dim, m=2)
frames3d = ndeye_einsum(base_shape, n_dim, m=3)
```

#### Approach #2

Again, from the same linked post, we can also reshape to 2D and assign into step-sized sliced array along the cols, like so -

```
def ndeye_reshape(base_shape, n_dim, m):
    N = (n_dim**np.arange(m)).sum()
    out = np.zeros(list(base_shape) +  [n_dim]*m)
    out.reshape(-1,n_dim**m)[:,::N] = 1
    return out
```

This again works on a view and hence should be equally efficient as approach #1.

#### Approach #3

Another way would be to use integer-based indexing. So, for example for assigning into `frames3d` in one-go, it would be -

```
I = np.arange(n_dim)
frames3d[..., I, I, I] = 1
```

Generalizing that becomes -

```
def ndeye_ellipsis_indexer(base_shape, n_dim, m):
    I = np.arange(n_dim)
    indexer = tuple([Ellipsis]+[I]*m)
    out = np.zeros(list(base_shape) +  [n_dim]*m)
    out[indexer] = 1
    return out
```

---

#### Extending to higher-dims with view

The dims along base_shape are basically replications of elements from the last `m` dims. As such, we can get those higher dims as a higher-dim array view with `np.broadcast_to`. We will create basically a m-dim identity array and then broadcast-view into higher dims. This would be applicable across all three approaches posted earlier. To demonstrate, how to use it on the `einsum` based solution, we would have -

```
# Create m-dim "trailing-base" array, basically a m-dim identity array
def ndeye_einsum_trailingbase(n_dim, m):
    out = np.zeros([n_dim]*m)
    diag_view = np.einsum('i'*m+'->...i',out)
    diag_view[:] = 1
    return out

def ndeye_einsum_view(base_shape, n_dim, m):
    trail_base = ndeye_einsum_trailingbase(n_dim, m)
    return np.broadcast_to(trail_base, list(base_shape) +  [n_dim]*m)
```

Thus, again we would have, e.g. -

```
frames3d = ndeye_einsum_view(base_shape, n_dim, m=3)
```

This would be a view into a m-dim array and hence efficient both on memory and performance.

Comment: I didn't know you can use `einsum` to produce views nor that it is possible to use it with `ellipses `. I tested it and is slightly faster than my simple approach.

Comment: @scleronomic Check out `Extending to higher-dims with view` section for a view output (if that works out for you) for even better performance.

Comment: `np.eye` uses `out.flat[::N+1] =1` to set the diagonal.  For 3d, the step could be `N*N+N`, or generalizing as you do in `ndeye_einsum_trailingbase`, `step = np.sum(out.strides)//out.strides[-1]`.

Comment: Since the `strides` in your `diag_view` is the sum of the strides of the `out`, this also works:  `as_strided(out, (out.shape[0],), (np.sum(out.strides),))[:]=1`.  But the `einsum` approach is fastest.

Comment: @hpaulj Appreciate the feedback. Those sound like what I did with app#2 and possibly could be extended to get the trailing base variant.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to have an identity matrix along the *last two dimensions* of the array, is to use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and specifying the resulting shape the ndarray should have (*this does not generalize to higher dimensions*):

```
base_shape = (10, 11, 12)
n_dim = 4

frame2d = np.broadcast_to(np.eye(n_dim), a.shape+(n_dim,)*2)
```

---

```
print(frame2d.shape)
# (10, 11, 12, 4, 4)

print(frame2d)

array([[[[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1.]],

         [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        ...
```

Comment: Did you check against `frame3d` too?

Comment: Yes, since I'm using `np.eye` here it only works for a `2d` identity matrix along the last 2 axes @divakar

Comment: I mean, did you check against `frames3d` from the question?

Comment: Nah just double cheked and `np.broadcast_to(np.eye(n_dim), a.shape+(n_dim,)*3)` does not produce OPs `frames3d`. This approahc only works for the 2d case @divakar